# Is there another way to write the following function without the for loop in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am trying to write the following function without the for loop. Note that I am trying to replicate the function `diag()`.

```
selfdiag <- function(a) {
  j <- c()
  for (i in 1:ncol(a)) {
    j[i] <- a[i, i]
  }
  return(j)
}
```

Consider that:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol = 2)
```

The function `selfdiag()` should create the same result as `diag()`.
Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: `mat[row(mat)==col(mat)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data frame with the row and column indices for the diagonal and use it to extract the diagonal values from the matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol = 2)
```

The `diag()` way to do it -

```
diag(mat)
[1] -0.5004046 -0.8785558
```

The other way to do it -

```
rows_cols <- data.frame(rows = c(1:ncol(mat)), cols = c(1:ncol(mat)))
mat2 <- mat[as.matrix(rows_cols)]
mat2
[1] -0.5004046 -0.8785558
```

Hope this helps!